# Google Datastore what is a good model in Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, nosql

Hello I'm new at Datastore and Python but I have to model my data and ingest it to the google datastore and I'm a bit lost !

I read all about Modeling Entity Relationships and Data Modeling in Python (so I understand one to many or many to many relationship). But i have a simple question I don't know how to answer !

For example, my data are result of sport match. In a basic SQL databse I would have  something like that :

TABLE:Match |
IDmatch
Name of the competition
matchday
winner
IDteam1
IDteam2

and then

Table:TEAM |
IDteam
playername
playerbirth
playerposition

So I would be able to know simply the name of all player who have played in the match with a certain id. How does it work in the database ? Doi I have to use one to many or many to many relationship or something else ?

Thank you to help :)

Answer (score 3):

You would [create entities](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#creating_entities) for Match, Team and Player. You may choose to make Team a [parent entity](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#Overview) of Player, however if Players move Teams you may opt to relate the two via [Key Properties](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#types) instead. You may chose to de-normalize team data onto the match for easier retrieval (since you cannot perform JOIN queries).

A typical model may look like this:

```
class Team(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()

class Player(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  date_of_birth = ndb.DateProperty()
  position = ndb.StringProperty()
  team = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Team)

  # denormalized properties
  team_name = ndb.StringProperty()

class Match(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  team1 = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Team)
  team2 = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Team)
  winning_team = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Team)

  # denormalized properties
  team1_name = ndb.StringProperty()
  team2_name = ndb.StringProperty()
  winning_team_name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

That should be a starting point to get you going.

Comment: Ok, thank you that help me a lot but what do you mean when you write "de-normalize team" it's not in the google doc i read so far

Comment: A typical sql query may be SELECT Player.Name AS PlayerName, Team.Name AS TeamName FROM Players INNER JOIN Teams ON Players.TeamID = Teams.TeamID, but this is not possible using datastore since you cannot perform JOIN queries. So instead, to get the team name you would either need to perform 2 queries, which can be expensive if you're querying for a lot of players, or denormalize the team name onto the player entity. You need to be careful though, as if the team name changes or the player changes team, you will need to make sure the data is kept up to date.